# Finding the set of all winning tic tac toe board states

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab

Here's my problem. I want to create an algorithm which generates an array of arrays of every possible winning board state for an n-dimensional tic-tac-toe board. Say you have an n = 2 board, meaning 2x2, then the function should return the following array:

```
wins = [
    [1,2],
    [1,3],
    [1,4],
    [2,4]
]
```

I know this isn't specifically a MATLAB problem, however I'm trying to expand my understanding of how MATLAB works. My general idea is an algorithm that does the following:

```
generate an n-dimensional board of zeros
1. Go to the first cell, record that index ([1,])
2. Go to the end of the row, and that's your first board state ([1,2])
3. Go to the end of the column, that's your second board state ([1,3])
4. Go to the end of the diagonal, that's your third board state ([2,3])
5. Advance to the next cell, repeat, checking if you have already created that board state first ([2,4] should be the only one it hasn't done)
```

I think I'm overthinking the problem, but I'm not sure how to approach it. Can someone give me some guidance how to do this in a MATLAB-y way? My guess is that traversing the matrix and just picking whole rows/colums/diagonals is easy, it's the 'checking if it exists' part that I'm not getting. How would you call this algorithm, in general? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Better idea: you don't do this square by square, you do this by dimension.  For each dimension on the board, you have these possibilities for the coordinate to vary or not through winning combinations:

- iterate through all the possible values, low to high
- iterate through all the possible values, high to low
- hold constant as the other dimensions iterate, but do so for each value in range, repeating for the other coordinates.

For instance, for a 4^3 board, let's look at the last coordinate (call them x1, x2, x3), x3.  Assume that you've already determined x1 will iterate low to high, x2 is constant at 2.  You will now treat x3 with:

- iterate through all the possible values, low to high

  - (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3)
- iterate through all the possible values, high to low

  - (1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 1)
- hold constant as the other dimensions iterate, but do so for each value in range, repeating for the other coordinates.

  - (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1)
  - (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 2)
  - (1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3), (3, 2, 3)

Does that get you moving?